# active directory c# website hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory

I am on a network with Active Directory. I wrote an MVC c# web application to show the person's name using the website in the header. The code for that is

```
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
 UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
 Debug.Writeline(user.DisplayName); //but when i host it in a local server (IIS) this keeps outputing my name
```

Whenever I access the website using some one else's computer I still get my name in the header.

How can I fix this so whenever I am on someone else's computer I get their name in the header?

Comment: i physically go to the persons computer and access the url on the network

Comment: You can't. You used to be able to do this, but it only ever sort of worked in Internet Explorer. The web server doesn't necessarily know anything about the client. You'll find some HTTP headers in the request that **seem** to tell you what you're looking for, but the reality is it's easy to fake these.

Comment: Also, if you see your name there, you setup the IIS application very wrong. You should see something like `ASPNET_USER` or `Network Service`, or perhaps a dedicated service account created for the purpose... but definitely **NOT** your day-to-day user account. Remember: all your code runs on the web server, as part of that process and in that context.

Comment: In your controller class, you should access login user information from `Controller.User` https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.user?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_User.

Answer (score 0):

`UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;` will show the user that the web application is running under. `UserPrincipal` is used when you are looking up an user account from ActiveDirectory (using `PrincipalContext`).

You should use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to look up the user that is accessing the site but do check to make sure `HttpContext.Current` is not null.

> [Documentation on `HttpContext` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: when i try this in my local it works but as soon as i do it in the server it gives me an empty string

Comment: are you sure the authentication is set up correctly on the server ?

Comment: i am pretty sure however what are some things i need to look out for 
but i believe it is setup correctly

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` can be null.

Comment: Yes @LexLi, it can be null. But what you cant use UserPrincipal to look up the user identity accessing the site

Comment: okay i will have a look at what i can do with this information and get back